# Load Python standard module from Modular Mojo

Tags: python, mojolang

From the available information and docs, Mojo claims to be fully compatible with Python syntax and modules.

However, from the [Playground notebook](https://www.modular.com/mojo), I can't seem to be able to load any module from Python:

```
In:
import os
import time
import sys
import numpy

Out:
error: Expression [1]:5:8: unable to locate module 'os'
import os
       ^

error: Expression [1]:7:8: unable to locate module 'time'
import time
       ^

error: Expression [1]:6:8: unable to locate module 'sys'
import sys
       ^

error: Expression [1]:8:8: unable to locate module 'numpy'
import numpy
       ^
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to start your Python notebook cell with the prefix "%%python", otherwise it will treat it as mojo code:

```py
%%python
import numpy as np
```

On the other hand, if you actually want to import Python modules from your mojo code, you have to use a mojo-specific syntax:

```
from PythonInterface import Python

# This is equivalent to Python's `import numpy as np`
let np = Python.import_module("numpy")
```

More info here: https://docs.modular.com/mojo/programming-manual.html#importing-python-modules